# Pricing of Binary or Digital Options or more generally options with discontinuous payoffs using PDEs

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-processes, black-scholes-pde

I am trying to find references (books, papers, etc.) for calculating $\mathbb E f(X_T)$, where $X_T$ is a diffusion and  $f$ is a real function that is not continuous, by means of solving a PDE or Feynman-Kac equation.

*Edit adressing the comments:* Even if the PDE has a solution it can only be shown to equal the expectation under certain conditions. That is why I am asking for a reference for the caclulation of the expectation as solution to a PDE and not about the PDE  and its solutions in itself.

Any such "verification theorem" basically uses the Ito formula for the value function and thus requires twice differentiability. This can only be ensured for the PDE solotion if the end data is continuous. So I am not interested in "it should just work" arguments but rather in answers or references to the "when" and "why.

Thank you

Comment: A silly suggestion, but can't you approximate your discontinous function with a better behaved one that satisfies the conditions?

Comment: That might be one solution. The technical mathematical requirements however, are often there for a reason,...

Comment: the hear kernel is smoothing and so even if the final data is not continuous the expectation is smooth for $t < T.$

Answer (score 1):

if we take a digital option and price under BS then you can do the whole thing by direct verification.

i.e. $N(d_2)$ solves the PDE and converges to the final pay-off pointwise.

So if the final pay-off has a finite number of jump discontinuities then subtract a linear combination of digitals to reduce to the continuous case.

Comment: That's a good starting point. To get to the more general case, the question now is: Is the cumulative distribution function of $X_t$ (SDE solution) also the solution to a PDE? Any ideas/pointers in that direction?

Comment: if you consider three times s < t < T. The expectation at time s will be the expectation of the value at time t which is the expectation of the value at time T. the value $T$ will be smooth since it's given by integrating a smooth kernel against an L1 function. So in any interval (0,t] it's smooth for t < T. i.e. it's smooth in (0,T).

Comment: It is still hard to see how this works for a general SDE. Explaining this in a comment is too much to ask, so do you have any references?

Answer (score 0):

$E\{f(X_T)\}$ can still exist even if $f$ is not continuous.

For example,
$$
\begin{equation}
f: x \mapsto
\begin{cases}
1, \, x >= 3 \\
0, \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

Then
$$
\begin{equation}
E\{f(X_T)\} = P(\{X_T >= 3\})
\end{equation}
$$

So, if you're example is a binary option which pays 1 if $X_T >= B$ and zero otherwise, and $\{X_t\}$ follows a standard diffusion,
$$
\begin{equation}
dX_t = X_t(r dt + \sigma dW_t)
\end{equation}
$$
you'll get
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
V_t &=& e^{-r\tau}\mathbb{E}\{1_{\{X_T >= B\}}|\mathcal{F_t}\} \\
&=& e^{-r\tau}P(\{X_T >= B\}) \\
&=& e^{-r\tau}\Phi\left(\frac{\log\left(\frac{X_t}{B}\right) + (r - \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2})\tau}{\sqrt{\tau}\sigma}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$,
where $\tau := T - t$.

To calculate $\mathbb{E}\{f(X_T) | \mathcal{F_t}\}$ you would find the stochastic differential of
$$\begin{equation}
e^{-rT}\mathbb{E}\{f(X_T) | \mathcal{F_t}\} = e^{-rt}V_t.
\end{equation}
$$
Set the "dt-term" to zero (which gives the Black-Scholes PDE) and set appropriate boundary conditions. The temporal end boundary condition is your payoff function. For upper and lower bounds in the spatial dimension you would need to set "suitably large" values. Actual numerical schemes for solving PDEs can be found in standard textbooks on PDEs.

Comment: This does not answer the question in any way.

Comment: "Thats why I am asking for a reference for the caclulation of the expectation and not the PDE solution."

Comment: "A reference for calculating $E(f_T)$ by means of solving a PDE or Feynman-Kac equation."

Comment: Yeah, I read that after =) Is he asking for both?

Comment: He wants to know how to price Binary options (or more generally Options with discontinuous payoffs) using a PDE. But thank's for your comments, I made the question more clear!

Comment: Okay, solving PDEs, however, is a large subject in itself so I just laid out the general idea in my edit.

Comment: You still seem not to understand what I am after. The outlined procedure including the stochastic differential is exactly what I am interested in. However, for it to work, certain conditions need to be fulfilled. For example, most works require $f$ to be continuous. This is because the stochastic differential you mention usually requires the conditional expectation (or price of the option) to be twice differentiable, which is the case if $f$ is continuous. And so on... Do you have references for your outlined method of finding a PDE for discontinuous $f$?

Comment: No, you are wrong. You're not differentiating f, you are differentiating the conditional expectation. You require only that f is Borel-measurable. The function f is your boundary condition.

Comment: Do you even bother to read what others write? You say "you are differentiating the conditional expectation", yes that is what I have just said: "[this] requires the conditional expectation [...] to be twice differentiable". How do you ensure differentiability of the conditional expectation? If you are so sure, PLEASE give a reference already!

Comment: Sorry, you did write that. I don't have a reference to link to. Do you have a reference to the requirement "f is continuous"? It should be sufficient to have f Borel-measurable (and integrable).

Comment: Yes, e.g.: in Karatzas&Shreve Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus Theorem 5.7.6 (p. 366)

Comment: Ok, I don't have that book, but it's a well-known and respected book. Do they write f continuous as a sufficient or necessary condition? Sufficient I guess?

Comment: Of course, otherwise my question would be stupid :-) What book do you use?

Comment: I have a book called Stochastic Calculus and its applications, by Fima C Klebaner. My guess, in lack of better references, is that it is sufficient if f is Borel-measurable. Mark Joshi made some good comments also about the expectation being smooth, because you are integrating against the heat kernel.

Comment: Looking at Theorem 6.6. of Klebaner, only states that if you have a solution to the PDE, then it is the expectation. On the followin pave (154) he explains, that the converse it not true. But I do not understand when it is true. Also it is not the heat kernel (only in the simple case where $X$ is Brownian motion)